# What algorithm can I apply to this DAG?

Tags: algorithm, tree, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have a DAG representing a list of properties. These properties are such that if a>b, then a has a directed edge to b. It is transitive as well, so that if a>b and b>c, then a has a directed edge to c.

However, the directed edge from a to c is superfluous because a has a directed edge to b and b has a directed edge to c. How can I prune all these superfluous edges? I was thinking of using a minimum spanning tree algorithm, but I'm not really sure what is the appropriate algorithm to apply in this situation

I suppose I could do a depth first search from each node and all its outgoing edges and compare if it can reach certain nodes without using certain edges, but this seems horribly inefficient and slow.

After the algorithm is complete, the output would be a linear list of all the nodes in an order that is consistent with the graph. So if a has three directed edges to b,c, and d. b and c also each of which has a directed edge to d, the output could be either abcd or acbd.

Comment: What would you do if a>b>d and a>c>d ?

Comment: a would have two directed edges, one to b and c, each of which would have a directed edge to d.

Comment: But if a>b>d and a>c>d, and as you say a->b, a->c, b->d, and c->d, then will it be certain that either b->c or c->b?  I would think so, and that would make the problem much simpler, but you're talking about ">" in such a way that it doesn't sound like simple arithmetic....

Comment: why is a depth-first-search "horribly inefficient?

Comment: More specifically, if a>b>d and a>c>d, can it be known whether b>c or c>b? Or can they be equal? Or simply not comparable?

Comment: @John: The absence of an edge in either direction between b and c means that the result of this comparison is unknown or unknowable. The point is not to figure out if b>c or b<c -- for our purposes this is unimportant -- it is to preserve the "knowledge" *and* the "absence of knowledge" present in the input DAG.

Comment: @David Because I would have to apply it to each node in the graph to each other node, which seems like overkill to me. Maybe not, any thoughts?

@John I won't know whether b>c or b<c; in fact it is irrelevant. The algorithm is simply trying to make a linear list of elements that is consistent with the graph provided.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is called the [transitive reduction problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_reduction).  Formally speaking, you are looking for a minimal (fewest edges) directed graph, the transitive closure of which is equal to the transitive closure of the input graph.  (The diagram on the above Wikipedia link makes it clear.)

Apparently there exists an efficient algorithm for solving this problem that takes the same time as for producing a transitive closure (i.e. the more common inverse problem of adding transitive links instead of removing them), however the [link to the 1972 paper](http://scitation.aip.org/getabs/servlet/GetabsServlet?prog=normal&id=SMJCAT000001000002000131000001&idtype=cvips&gifs=yes) by Aho, Garey, and Ullman costs $25 to download, and some quick googling didn't turn up any nice descriptions.

**EDIT: [Scott Cotton's `graphlib`](https://code.google.com/p/stixar-graphlib/) contains a [Java implementation](https://code.google.com/p/stixar-graphlib/source/browse/trunk/src/java/stixar/graph/conn/Transitivity.java)!**  This Java library looks to be very well organised.

Comment: Thanks. Rereading your question, if all you actually need is a sequence of nodes consistent with the order, you can just use a topological sort (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) which may be simpler than a transitive reduction.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, after looking around a little more, I think a [Topologicalsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) is what I'm really after here.

Comment: s/topographical/topological/;

Answer (score 0):

If these are already n nodes with directed edges:

1. Starting from any point M, loop all its child edge, select the biggest child (like N), remove other edges, the complexity should be o(n) . If no N exists (no child edge, goto step 3).
2. start from N, repeat step 1.
3. start from point M, select the smallest parent node ( like T), remove others' edges.
4. start from T, repeat step 3.....

---

Actually it's just a ordering algorithm, and the totally complexity should be o(0.5n^2).

---

One problem is that if we want loop one node's parent nodes, then we need more memory to log edge so we can trace back from child to parent. This can be improved in the step 3 where we choose one node from the left nodes bigger than M, this means we need to keep a list of nodes to know what nodes are left..

Comment: I am given the graph in this form as input. I guess I should have been more specific. I am trying to retrieve a linear ordering of these properties such as a>b>c>d>etc using the graph.

Comment: How can one know what the "biggest" child is in step 1?

Comment: tmp = 0; for_each_child(current,a) { if(tmp > a) { remove_edge(current, a); } else tmp = a; } So each edge only checked once

Comment: If I understand you correctly, your algorithm will remove all out-edges but 1 from each node, leaving a collection of paths. -1. (If not, please clarify and I'll reconsider.)

Comment: @arsane: The code in your most recent comment is clearly broken -- which edges are removed by it will depend on the (unspecified) order in which children are considered in your for_each_child loop. Also, what is the quantity a measuring? Is that the position of that node in some topological ordering of the graph?